# How to know if job is running in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server

I need to know if a job is running in SQL Server 2000, so I can stop it using msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job.
 I found this code that works in 2005:

```
IF EXISTS(     
            select 1 
            from msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job  
            inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity on job.job_id = activity.job_id 
            where  
                activity.run_Requested_date is not null  
                and activity.stop_execution_date is null  
                and job.name = 'myjobname' 
            ) 
    BEGIN      

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job  @name_job; 
    END
```

However, in SQL 2000 msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity table does not exist. What could be the alternative solution?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe if a silly question, but why down vote if not giving a solution?

Comment: Probably because you do not demonstrate any attempt to find the answer yourself. Did you search? My search on "sql server 2000 is job running" returns many links. 2000 is also almost 2 decades old - knowledge of that version is declining rapidly. The second link in my search suggests you use sp_help_job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think saying you did no research is a bit harsh, so I'll throw you a bone...  Next time, spend 10-15 minutes googling, and you'd likely eventually stumble across this.

Try this...

```
DECLARE @jobname VARCHAR(100)

SET @jobname='my job name'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#jobs') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #jobs

CREATE TABLE #jobs (JOB_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, LAST_RUN_DATE INT, LAST_RUN_TIME INT, NEXT_RUN_DATE INT, NEXT_RUN_TIME INT, NEXT_RUN_SCHEDULE_ID INT, REQUESTED_TO_RUN INT, REQUEST_SOURCE INT, REQUEST_SOURCE_ID VARCHAR(100), RUNNING INT, CURRENT_STEP INT, CURRENT_RETRY_ATTEMPT INT, STATE INT)       

INSERT INTO #jobs EXEC MASTER.DBO.XP_SQLAGENT_ENUM_JOBS 1,NOTHING 

SELECT *
FROM #jobs e
JOIN MSDB..SYSJOBS j ON e.JOB_ID=j.JOB_ID
WHERE RUNNING=1
--AND j.name=@jobname
```

Comment: Thanks @JiggsJedi, I was having a problem because I was using linked servers, one was SQL 2000 and the other SQL 2012. Your answer helped me in solving my issue.